# what should be the value passed in function to connect to my google drive using java program?

Tags: java, google-drive-api

I got following code from google developers site:

```
package javaapplication24;
import com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse;
import com.google.api.services.drive.Drive;
import com.google.api.services.drive.model.File;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

// ...

public class NewClass {

// ...

/**
* Print a file's metadata.
*
 * @param args
* @param service Drive API service instance.
* @param fileId ID of the file to print metadata for.
*/

private static void printFile(Drive service, String fileId) {


try {
  File file = service.files().get(fileId).execute();

  System.out.println("Title: " + file.getTitle());
  System.out.println("Description: " + file.getDescription());
  System.out.println("MIME type: " + file.getMimeType());
} catch (IOException e) {
  System.out.println("An error occured: " + e);
}
}

/**
 * Download a file's content.
 *
 * @param service Drive API service instance.
 * @param file Drive File instance.
 * @return InputStream containing the file's content if successful,
 *         {@code null} otherwise.
 */
private static InputStream downloadFile(File file, Drive service) {
if (file.getDownloadUrl() != null && file.getDownloadUrl().length() > 0) {
  try {
    HttpResponse resp =
        service.getRequestFactory().buildGetRequest(new GenericUrl(file.getDownloadUrl()))
            .execute();
    return resp.getContent();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    // An error occurred.
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
  }
} else {
  // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
  return null;
}
}

// ...
}
```

I know i need to write a main function with this and call the functions printFile and DownloadFile but I am not getting what is to be passed in function as variable service?

Comment: Are we talking about an Android App?

Comment: no not an android app a java desktop app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to understand how it works first!

1. In order to download or print details about your files, you need to authenticate your app from your google account with right `scope`(permissions like readonly, modify/delete and so on).
2. Once authentication is done. You will get access token to access the data.

This is a small fragment of code that says what the `Drive service` means

```
     /**
     * Build and return an authorized Drive client service.
     * @return an authorized Drive client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Drive getDriveService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Drive.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
```

**Head on to this link to learn more about it**

https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/java

**Note: It would be unnecessarily long answer, if i copy paste the complete code here**

Comment: @DHRUVIPANDYA You are welcome. Don't forget, Documentation is our friend :)